# WebMatrix sql LIKE %

Tags: asp.net, sql, webmatrix

I am having trouble with the following query. It works when I execute it directly from WebMatrix with static parameters and returns a few rows, but not from my .cshtml page

```
var accounts = database.Query(
  @"SELECT Username, Email, row_count
  FROM (SELECT Username, Email, Count(0) OVER() as row_count, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @0 DESC) as row_number 
  FROM UserProfile 
  WHERE Username LIKE %@1% AND Email LIKE %@2%) as accounts
  WHERE row_number BETWEEN @3 AND @4",
  new object[] { sort, username, email, start, end });
```

When I replace the LIKE parameters @1 and @2 with static values it works, but it does not ORDER BY parameter @0

Comment: I guess you have to use `LIKE @1 AND Email LIKE @2` and pass `"%" + username + "%", "%" + email + "%"` as the parameters.

Answer (score 6):

Use this in your sql:

```
LIKE '%' + @1 + '%'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because @0 is being evaluated by the query as the literal value of the parameter, rather than the name of the table column - eg. if @0 is 'Username', the relevant part of the query is treated as being `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 'Username' DESC)`, not `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Username DESC)`.

The row number is therefore always evaluated as 1.

The solution is therefore to insert the value of @0 into the query string, not to treat it as a bind parameter. (This approach is generally deprecated due to the risk of SQL insertion attacks, but given that you should be able to guarantee the available values of @0 will be valid, it should be appropriate **in this case**.)

EDIT: An alternative approach - instead of using dynamic SQL, if you are unable to guarantee that @0 will be properly sanitised then you could use a case clause instead:

```
var accounts = database.Query(
  @"SELECT Username, Email, row_count FROM 
   (SELECT Username, 
           Email,
           Count(0) OVER() as row_count, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY row_group DESC) as row_number 
    FROM (SELECT Username, 
                 Email,
                 CASE @0
                     WHEN 'Username' THEN Username
                     WHEN 'Email' THEN Email
                     /* insert other valid cases here */
                 END as row_group
          FROM UserProfile 
          WHERE Username LIKE '%'+@1+'%' AND Email LIKE '%'+@2+'%') u
   ) as accounts
   WHERE row_number BETWEEN @3 AND @4",
  new object[] { sort, username, email, start, end });
```

Comment: i will have to sanitize my paramaters myself, is there anything else built into asp.net for sql sanitization

Comment: @ambiguousPanda: I'm not familiar enough with asp.net to be able to answer that. I have added an alternative solution to my answer, that does not require dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with webMatrix syntax; but logically it seems to me the dbengine doesn't understand the variables %@1% and %@2%  try using string concatenation to have the value of the variable passed instead of the variable.

So...

```
WHERE USERname like %" & @1 & "% AND Email like %" & @2 & "%) as accounts
```

Comment: "try using string concatenation" :( No, just no -- at least, not in the application code

Answer (score 0):

**My Problem**

I am using ASP.NET Webpages and am having a similar issue wher I am using Database.Query() to execute a SQL `SELECT` statement using a `LIKE` clause.

**My Solution**

Here is a snippet of code that shows how I resolved my issue:

```
qString = @"
Select *
From
    [Product]
Where Lastname like @0
Order By LastName";

using (var db = Database.Open("StarterSite"))
{
    data = db.Query(qString, "%" + searchTxt + "%");
}
```