# Webmatrix - List item as a search term?

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

I have a search page, and i am trying to pull search terms from a query string, and search some text for that term using the LIKE SQl command. here's the code:

```
string searchTerm = "";

List<string> argList = new List<string>();

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["searchTerm"]))
{
searchTerm = Request.QueryString["searchTerm"];
}

if (searchTerm != "")
{
argList.Add(searchTerm);
selectQueryString += "WHERE FullDescription LIKE '%@0%' ";

numOfArguments++; //increment numOfArguments by 1
}
queryResults = db.Query(selectQueryString, argArray);
```

If i run the page, it doesn't give me an error, but it says that it can't find any matches, even though i KNOW there are matches. As a test, i replaced the '%@0%' with '%villa%' and it works perfectly.

Maybe it's not recognizing @0 as a string?

Comment: I am not 100% on this, but I think it get's confused by `@`

Comment: i think you're right, but that's the only way i can insert my variable into the query. I'll try wrapping some quotes around it in different places

Comment: I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821/sql-server-2000-5-escape-an-underscore You might be able to escape `@` in the same manner.

Comment: figured it out, found it elsewhere on SO after a lot of searching. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215246/webmatrix-sql-like

Comment: second answer down was how i achieved it

Comment: I'm glad you found it. I suggest you answer this question yourself with what you found and accept it.

Comment: Thank you. And thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was accepting the @0 as a literal. I finally found a way of seperating out.

```
'%' + @0 + '%'
```